# node-webkit window width issue

Tags: javascript, webkit, node-webkit, chromium-embedded

Before minimizing the node-webkit window it looked like this:

[image: Before minimizing]

After restoring the node-webkit window it looked like this:

[image: After restoring]

package.json

```
   {
      "name": "Gallay",
      "description": "Simplified Billing",
      "version": "0.1",
      "main": "index.html",
      "window": {
        "icon": "icons/16.png", 
        "show": true,
        "toolbar": false,
        "frame": true,
        "position": "center",
        "width": 507,
        "height": 570,
        "min_width": 507,
        "min_height": 570,
    "max_width": 507,
        "max_height": 570
      }
}
```

> I need fixed width while minimizing and restoring the node-webkit window. How can I solve the above problem?

Comment: Have you tried to fix the window's width with the almighty `$(window).resize()`?

Comment: @grmmph after you'd mentioned, I'd tried it. The window is being resized on restoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After including jQuery and the following JavaScript, the problem can be solved.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).resize(function(){
            window.resizeTo(507,570);
            window.focus();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to package.json:  `"resizable": false` and remove `min_width`, `min_height`, `max_width`, `max_height`.